# Syncing users on two firebase projects

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I have one firebase with a Users list, and Want to have the users that use that login to be able to login to the second firebase project with the same credentials.

I basically would like two firebase projects with synced user lists?

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: This is somewhat of an anti-pattern in Firebase. If the data in the two projects needs to be separated, so does the user data. If the user data needs to be shared, that probably applies to the other data in the project too. So it sounds a bit like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you clarify why the user data should be shared, but the other data not, between these projects?

Comment: Outside of that, it'd be https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth and/or https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/import-users